# want to get old value in select through array

Tags: arrays, laravel, select

I want to select the old value of the particular user role,

Roles: administrator, manager, teamleader, agent

blade.php

```php
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="roles">{{ trans('cruds.user.fields.roles') }}*
          <span class="btn btn-info btn-xs select-all">{{ trans('global.select_all') }}</span>
          <span class="btn btn-info btn-xs deselect-all">{{ trans('global.deselect_all') }}</span></label>
      <select name="roles[]" id="roles" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" required>
          @foreach($roles as $id => $roles)
              <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ (in_array($id, old('roles', [])) || isset($user) && $user->roles->contains($id)) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $roles }}</option>
           @endforeach
      </select>
</div>
```

UsersController.php

```php
public function edit(User $user)
{
        $roles = Role::get()->pluck('name', 'name');

        return view('admin.users.edit', compact('user', 'roles'));
}

 public function update(UpdateUsersRequest $request, User $user)
{
   $user->update($request->all());
   $roles = $request->input('roles') ? $request->input('roles') : [];
   $user->syncRoles($roles);

   return redirect()->route('users.index');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="roles">{{ trans('cruds.user.fields.roles') }}*
          <span class="btn btn-info btn-xs select-all">{{ trans('global.select_all') }}</span>
          <span class="btn btn-info btn-xs deselect-all">{{ trans('global.deselect_all') }}</span></label>
      <select name="roles[]" id="roles" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" required>
          @foreach($roles as $index => $role)
            <option value="{{$role->id}}" @if (request("roles")){{ (in_array($role->id, request("roles")) ? "selected":"") }}@endif>{{$role->role_name}}</option>
           @endforeach
      </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Now working ```Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object```

Comment: @itxrahulsingh Show your data roles

Comment: @itxrahulsingh seem you don't know about your data from controller clearly.

Comment: why alias $roles is your role id?

Comment: actually I don't understant what you want

Comment: what your $roles look like? print it out!

Comment: bcos of this passing in user controller edit function ```$roles = Role::get()->pluck('name', 'name');

            return view('admin.users.edit', compact('user', 'roles'));```

Comment: U don't event pass *id* into roles. Why you use $id in blade.

Comment: you want to check with **id** but u pluck only name. Is it correct?

Comment: I updated the ```UsersController``` now you can what am doing

Comment: check your $roles properly and try to dump your data. This will work!

Comment: after updating the pluck this pluck('name','name); to this pluck("name"); able to get old values but when update the role it will auto update secound role

Comment: means 1.admin, 2.manager , if i select admin it will update  manager

Comment: If you want to get **id, and role** you need to use Role::all(); No need use pluck.

Comment: now your code working but still not getting the old value as selected